# Python Matching Complex String with Regex

Tags: python, regex, string, list, filter

I have the following test string:

```
test_str = `It isn't directed at all,' said the White Rabbit;
```

My current regular expression uses `re.sub` to filter out the punctuation so that I can do my own operations.

My current regex is `re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9'\s]", '', test_str)`

The output from above is:

`['It', "isn't", 'directed', 'at', "all'", 'said', 'the', 'White', 'Rabbit']`

The error can be seen at `all'` when it is suppose to be storing `all` only.

How do you store words with `'s` and also ignore `'` that comes after a punctuation? In this case, `all,'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import re
test_str = "`It isn't directed at all,' said the White Rabbit;"
a = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z0-9'\s]", '', test_str)
a = re.sub(r"'[ ]", ' ', a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regular expression:

```
print(re.sub('["!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~''](?!\w+)', '', test_str))
```

Output:

```
It isn't directed at all said the White Rabbit
```

Comment: I tried working on it but its a little bit complex from what i wanna achieve. Thank you so help for ur help !

Answer (score 0):

Here are other solutions

```py
re.sub("\'[^\w]",' ', test_str)
re.sub("\'[\s]",' ', test_str)
re.sub("\'(?!\w)",'', test_str)
re.sub("\'(?=\s)",'', test_str)
```